# How to programmatically get an Macro object?

Tags: .net, vba, ms-office

I have a Word.Application object. How can I programmatically get an Macro object by using the Word Object Model?

Comment: possible duplicate of [return a list of all macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922772/return-a-list-of-all-macros)

Comment: See also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262961#appliesto

Answer (score 2):

In brief, you need to set a reference to Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility library.

You can then reference your project through ThisDocument.VBProject.VBComponents collection.

For example:

```
for i = 1 to thisdocument.vbproject.vbcomponents.count
    debug.print thisdocument.vbproject.vbcomponents(i).name
next i
```

Code in each of these components can be accessed through the ThisDocument.VBProject.VBComponents(i).CodeModule object.

Edit: Workbook to Document

Comment: Thanks. I am using .net framework. I can get the VBComponents now by using e.g. mobjWordApp.Documents(1).VBProject.VBComponents, but it seems I cannot find the CodeModule property. Also is there anyway I can get the properties of the Macro object because actually I want to get the information of the Digital Signature details of my Macro.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the .net framework, so I can't help you here, sorry.