# How to Call Subs from an Add-In Directly

Tags: vba, excel

So it's obviously easy to write code that will call a sub/function that is in an add-in library via VBA code, simply by doing

```
call myFunctionOrSub
```

However, is there a way to allow users to directly call public subs in an add-in? For example, when the user goes to Tools -> Macros and pulls up this screen:

[image: Macro Selection]

I would like to add to the list of macros in that box all Subs which are included in add-ins that are linked to for the file. That is, I have a library (library.xlam) that is referenced by this current workbook. In this library.xlam file, I have Subs (such as copyToResults). I want copyToResults to appear as a runnable macro in this list. Is there a way to do that?

The only solution I could come up with was to create a Sub in my test file for each Sub in library.xlam. This Sub in the test file would do nothing by call library's Sub. However, this is terrible for the purpose of having external libraries and terrible for scalability, so we definitely don't want to go this route.

Comment: This is the one case where it makes sense to use a Personal.xls(m) workbook instead of an add-in for your custom routines. If they are in the Personal workbook they WILL display in the Macro dialog.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I had found that solution as well, but was really hoping for this to work through the Macro dialog. Well, unless someone else comes up with a miracle, I guess I'll be stuck with it. Thank you.

Comment: You can probably type the fully-scoped name of the macro into the Macro dialog and run it, even though it is not listed. But yeah, that is not great either.

Comment: One final thing here. You can of course flesh out your add-in workbook to include a userform that offers essentially the same functionality as the built-in Macro dialog. This would allow users of your add-in a familiar way to select and run individual routines in the add-in. To display the userform you could define a keyboard shortcut. ALT-F8 opens the normal Macro dialog. So you could perhaps use CONTROL-ALT-F8 for the custom version. The add-in itself could include code to setup the shortcut. You could also have it create a Ribbon item to launch the userform. So there are options still.

Comment: I would second @ExcelHero and go with a customised ribbon - much more user-friendly and contained.

Comment: @Excelhero.  Your very good comments reminded me that I'd like to do you course, but figured I'd know a lot of it so couldn't justify the cost.... any thoughts?

Comment: @HarveyFrench I am certain that you will be pleasantly surprised. I've had some of the most experienced most knowledgeable professionals find tremendous value in it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a form in your xlam with a list box.
2. Use the script from this post to populate your form. You will have to change some excel settings.
   [Get a list of the macros of a module in excel, and then call all those macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132276/get-a-list-of-the-macros-of-a-module-in-excel-and-then-call-all-those-macros)

Here is my code from my form:

```
Private Sub btnCancel_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub btnExecute_Click()

    Application.Run "macros.xlam!" & lstMacros.Value
    Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim pj As VBProject
Dim vbcomp As VBComponent
Dim curMacro As String, newMacro As String
Dim x As String
Dim y As String
Dim macros As String

On Error Resume Next
curMacro = ""
Documents.Add

For Each pj In Application.VBE.VBProjects

     For Each vbcomp In pj.VBComponents
            If Not vbcomp Is Nothing Then
                If Not vbcomp.CodeModule = "Utilities" Then
                    For i = 1 To vbcomp.CodeModule.CountOfLines
                       newMacro = vbcomp.CodeModule.ProcOfLine(Line:=i, _
                          prockind:=vbext_pk_Proc)

                       If curMacro <> newMacro Then
                          curMacro = newMacro

                            If curMacro <> "" And curMacro <> "app_NewDocument" Then
                                frmMacros.lstMacros.AddItem curMacro
                            End If

                       End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If
     Next

Next
End Sub
```

In the end mine looked like this:
[Macros Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7RQN.png)